# How do i combine condition statements with this particular lambda expression?

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, java-8, predicate

I have a java method written using lambda expressions where i need to add more conditions, and i was forbidden from using classical if and elses. This is my current code that checks if getInstrument has the correct ENUM:

```java
public static Predicate<Deal> isDeal() {
  return  i ->
    i.getInstrument() == ENUM1
      || i.getInstrument() == ENUM2
      || i.getInstrument() == ENUM3;
}
```

To this code, i need to add a condition that checks if `i.getGroup()` is  null and and then keep checking if the enums are correct. I also need to add a condition that, if `i.getGroup() != null and i.getGroup() != "NODEAL"` and `i.getInstrument()` is not an ENUM2 or ENUM3, it returns i. This is how i would write it with classical if and elses:

```java
public static Predicate<Deal> is Deal() {

    if ( i.getGroup() == null && i.getInstrument() == ENUM1
                || i.getInstrument() == ENUM2
                || i.getInstrument() == ENUM3) {
      return i;
    } else if ( i.getGroup() != null && i.getGroup() == "DEAL" && 
    i.getInstrument() != ENUM2 || i.getInstrument() != ENUM3) {
      return i;
    }
}
```

How could i write this using lambda?

Comment: Tip: The classical if needs parentheses after the && or it won't work as you expected

Comment: why are you not allowed to use "classical if and elses"? And, please, make sure it complies, now it makes little sense with `Predicate<Deal> is Deal()` - `i` is definitely not a `Predicate`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I assumed it is homework

Comment: @AndrewTobilko because the client wants it with Lambda expressions.

Comment: In the second code you are missing a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
Predicate<Deal> isDeal() {
        return deal -> deal.getGroup() == null 
                       && EnumSet.of(Instrument.ENUM1, 
                                     Instrument.ENUM2,
                                     Instrument.ENUM3)
                                 .contains(deal.getInstrument())
                ||
                "DEAL".equals(deal.getGroup()) 
                && !EnumSet.of(Instrument.ENUM2,
                                     Instrument.ENUM3)
                                 .contains(deal.getInstrument())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public static Predicate<Deal> isDeal() {
   return  i->
        (i.getGroup() == null 
        && (i.getInstrument() == ENUM1
            || i.getInstrument() == ENUM2
            || i.getInstrument() == ENUM3)
        )
        ||
        ( i.getGroup() != null 
          && i.getGroup() == "DEAL" 
          && i.getInstrument() != ENUM2 && i.getInstrument() != ENUM3);
}
```

PS: Keep in mind that you should compare string with `equals` not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your business domain, but I tried to make the condition more expressive, readable and maintainable. I would also ask the client *why* they want it with lambdas because I see no reason to use them here. An `if-else` statement would give you the same without the overhead.

```
public Predicate<Deal> isDeal() {
    return isGroupAbsent().or(isGroupPresent());
}

private Predicate<Deal> isGroupPresent() {
    Instrument i = i.getInstrument();
    return d -> "DEAL".equals(d.getGroup()) && i != ENUM2 && i != ENUM3;
}

private Predicate<Deal> isGroupAbsent() {
    Instrument i = i.getInstrument();
    return d -> d.getGroup() == null && (i == ENUM1 || i == ENUM2 || i == ENUM3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for the `ternary operator ? :`

But there still is a problem with your last condition, what should it return, `true` or `false` ? Knowing the `Predicate<T>` signature is `boolean test(T t);`

```
public static Predicate<Deal> isDeal() {
    return  i-> i.getGroup() == null ? 
                    EnumSet.of(ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3).contains(i.getInstrument()) : 
                    !"DEAL".equals(i.getGroup()) ? 
                        !EnumSet.of(ENUM2, ENUM3).contains(i.getInstrument()) : 
                        false; // What do you put here? This is missing in your question  
}
```